# EF Core .netcore , NetStandard1.6 and Xamarin

Tags: entity-framework, xamarin, .net-core

Im trying to Xamarin and NetStandard and EF Core running.

I got  "hello world" running using **netstandard.Library 1.3**
EF however didnt have a DB to operate on.
So I need to add a migration.
But **dotnet ef** seems to have a dependency on **netstandard.library1.6**

i get this error  from ef tools when using netstandard1.3

> c:\App1>dotnet ef migrations add FirstMigration Project App1
>   (.NETStandard,Version=v1.3) will be compiled because the version or
>   bitness of the CLI changed since the last build Compiling App1 for
>   .NETStandard,Version=v1.3 C:\App1\project.json(10,32): warning NU1007:
>   Dependency specified was NETStandard.Library >= 1.3.0 but ended up
>   with NETStandard.Library 1.6.0. Compilation failed.
>       21 Warning(s)

So if I change projtect.json to have a dependency on netstandard1.6 instead of 1.3

```
{
"supports": {},
"dependencies": {
"Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore": "1.1.0",
"Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SQLite": "1.1.0",
"Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools": "1.1.0-preview4-final",
"Microsoft.NETCore.Platforms": "1.1.0",
"sqlite-net-pcl": "1.3.1",
"Xamarin.Forms": "2.3.4.184-pre1",
**"NETStandard.Library": "1.6.0"**,
"Microsoft.NETCore.Portable.Compatibility": "1.0.1"
},
"frameworks": {
**"netstandard1.6"**: { "imports": "portable-net45+win8+wpa81+wp8" }
},
"tools": {
"Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools": "1.1.0-preview4-final",
"Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools.DotNet": "1.1.0-preview4-final"
}
}
```

I get these compile errors

> Your project is not referencing the ".NETPlatform,Version=v5.0"
>   framework. Add a reference to ".NETPlatform,Version=v5.0" in the
>   "frameworks" section of your project.json, and then re-run NuGet
>   restore.  App1              Error     Project App1 is not compatible with uap10.0
>   (UAP,Version=v10.0) / win10-x64-aot. Project App1 supports: 
>   netstandard1.6 (.NETStandard,Version=v1.6)                  Error     One or more
>   projects are incompatible with UAP,Version=v10.0 (win10-x86).

**is there a way to use netstandard 1.6  in such a project?**

Comment: .NET Core has been moving too fast (.NET Core SDK 1.0 rc3 now with VS2017 RC). So it would be difficult to tell if what you met is fixed already in latest tooling. You might upgrade and try again.